# Display text and Dropdown in 2 lines instead of 4 lines

Tags: dropdownbox

we have **4 Text & Dropdown** with each have different dropdown boxes displaying in **4 lines** as below :

[image]

We want to display **2 Text & Dropdown in one line & other 2 below that line.**

I tried `float : left ; , display :block; display: inline-block` nothing worked for me properly , instead it displayed like this :

[image]

If anyone want , here is the [site link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock.html)

```
 <dt>
   <label class="required">
   <em>*size</em>
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
   <div>
      <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
         <option value="4397" price="30">Mini ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs30.00</option>
         <option value="4398" price="40">Small  ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs40.00</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</dd>
<dt>
   <label class="required">
   <em>*Frame style</em>
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
   <div>
      <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
         <option value="4397" price="30">Cherry</option>
         <option value="4398" price="40">Natural</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</dd>
<dt>
   <label class="required">
   <em>*Frame style Size</em>
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
   <div>
      <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
         <option value="4397" price="30">0.75</option>
         <option value="4398" price="40">1.25</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</dd>
<dt>
   <label class="required">
   <em>*Matboard</em>
   </label>
</dt>
<dd>
   <div>
      <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
         <option value="4397" price="30">Black</option>
         <option value="4398" price="40">White</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</dd>
```

**css**

```
 <style>

    .required {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }

    .product-options dd {
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    }

    dd {
        display: block;
        -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: Please, always use proper indentation.

Comment: @Roope sorry , let me edit the question.....

Comment: span elements are quite good at aligning themselves horizontally.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Thanks a lot for suggestion, i will follow it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css, Let me know if this is what you need ?

```
.product-options dt, .product-options dd {
    width: 90px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: What do you need in that?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use bootstrap grid system for better look.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <form>
   <div class="row">
    
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select Text</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select Text</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
      </div>
    </div>
      
   </div>
   
   
   <div class="row">
    
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select Text</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select Text</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
      </div>
    </div>
      
   </div>
     
     
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ,  i tried your code, but as this is magento site, the values willl be saved in database & html structure  of inspect element is different than in real file, is there any way to fix the issue with only css ?

Comment: Thanks for support,  i found solution , i 'm sorry that as i am poor in coding , i failed to follow your solution properly .....

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 Its fine..Glad to help you. and  you can edit and use this pen in your code.. http://codepen.io/shivk/pen/ggMaOE

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 Welcome dude! and Keep Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```css
.required {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.product-options dd {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

dd {
    display: block;
    
  float:left;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<dt>
<label class="required">
<em>*size</em>
</label>
</dt>
<dd>
<div>
<select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<option value="4397" price="30">Mini ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs30.00</option>
<option value="4398" price="40">Small  ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs40.00</option>
</select>
</div>
</dd>



<dt>
<label class="required">
<em>*Frame style</em>
</label>
</dt>
<dd>
<div>
<select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<option value="4397" price="30">Cherry</option>
<option value="4398" price="40">Natural</option>
</select>
</div>
</dd>



<dt>
<label class="required">
<em>*Frame style Size</em>
</label>
</dt>
<dd>
<div>
<select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<option value="4397" price="30">0.75</option>
<option value="4398" price="40">1.25</option>
</select>
</div>
</dd>



<dt>
<label class="required">
<em>*Matboard</em>
</label>
</dt>
<dd>
<div>
<select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<option value="4397" price="30">Black</option>
<option value="4398" price="40">White</option>
</select>
</div>
</dd>
```

Comment: Thanks ,  i tried your code, but as this is magento site, the values willl be saved in database & html structure  of inspect element is different than in real file, is there any way to fix the issue with only css ?

Comment: Thanks, i updated your css code, can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock1.html)

Comment: can't able to access your link

Comment: can you please check now again..... please try in private window also...

Comment: remove margin-top:50px; from .required and dd class in css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133007/discussion-between-user7357089-and-user5348fh8y5).

Comment: Thanks for support,  i found solution , i 'm sorry that as i am poor in coding , i failed to follow your solution properly .....

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

1. with bootstrap
2. With Table
3. With Div

this is [Demo and Code](https://jsfiddle.net/c6tcxn2u/) using div

CSS

```
.row{
      float:left;
      width:100%;
    }
   .col{
      float:left;
      width:50%
    }
   .required {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<label class="required">
   <em>*size</em>
   </label>
 <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">Mini ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs30.00</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">Small ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs40.00</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col">
 <label class="required">
   <em>*Frame style</em>
   </label>
<select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">Cherry</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">Natural</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<label class="required">
   <em>*Frame style Size</em>
   </label>
  <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">0.75</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">1.25</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col">
 <label class="required">
   <em>*Matboard</em>
   </label>
<select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">Black</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">White</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope It Helps :)

this is [Demo and Code](https://jsfiddle.net/hncsm89s/) using table

TRY THIS FOR YOUR CODE

```
.product-options dt {
float:left;
max-width:20%;
}
.product-options dd {
float:left;
max-width:28%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried your code, but as this is magento site, the values willl be saved in database & html structure of inspect element is different than in real file, is there any way to fix the issue with only css ?

Comment: can you please visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock.html) and check is there any way to solve only with css

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 check updated answer. Hope you want this.

Comment: Thanks, its looking in 2 lines, please help me to make it look better , now its displaying [like this](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock1.html)

Comment: after i tried your code, now i cant able to select dropdown options, can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock1.html)

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 add `.product-options .last{height:90px;}` to enable dropdowns.Change other css properties like width,overflow etc to make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

**styles:**

```
dd, dt{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

dt{
  margin-top: 15px !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,  i tried your code, but as this is magento site, the values willl be saved in database & html structure  of inspect element is different than in real file, is there any way to fix the issue with only css ?

Comment: can you please visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock.html) and check is there any way to solve only with css

Comment: @user5348fh8y5, Try this updated code in your styles

Comment: Thanks, its looking in 2 lines, please help me to make it look better , now its displaying [like this](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock2.html)

Comment: after i tried your code, now i cant able to select dropdown options, can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock2.html)

Comment: Thanks for support,  i found solution , i 'm sorry that as i am poor in coding , i failed to follow your solution properly .....

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="s">
        <dt>
           <label class="required">
             <em>*size</em>
           </label>
        </dt>
        <dd class="d">
         <div>
           <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
              <option value="4397" price="30">Mini ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs30.00</option>
              <option value="4398" price="40">Small  ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs40.00</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="s">
     <dt>
        <label class="required">
           <em>*Frame style</em>
        </label>
     </dt>
     <dd class="d">
        <div>
           <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
              <option value="4397" price="30">Cherry</option>
              <option value="4398" price="40">Natural</option>
           </select>
        </div>
     </dd>
  </div>
```

```
<style>
  .s{
     display: inline-flex;
    }
  .d{
     margin: 0;
    }

  .required {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
            }

  .product-options dd {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
   }

  dd {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , but as this is magento site, the values willl be saved in database & html structure  of inspect element is different than in real file, is there any way to fix the issue with only css ?

Comment: check my answer !

Comment: is there any way we can fix the issue with only help of css ?

Comment: check that out man! its working just by changing css , i had updated the answer

Comment: i hope now u wont ask me to built your whole page dude , Check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133006/discussion-between-satyam-pathak-and-user5348fh8y5).

Comment: Thanks for support,  i found solution , i 'm sorry that as i am poor in coding , i failed to follow your solution properly .....

Answer (score -1):

Make use of surrounding wrappers per 2 dropdowns to create the rows.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <dt>
        <label class="required">
            <em>*size</em>
        </label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <div>
            <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
                <option value="4397" price="30">Mini ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs30.00</option>
                <option value="4398" price="40">Small  ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs40.00</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        <label class="required">
            <em>*Frame style</em>
        </label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <div>
            <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
                <option value="4397" price="30">Cherry</option>
                <option value="4398" price="40">Natural</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </dd>
</div>
```

Then you can apply `display: inline-block` together with `vertical-align: middle` to properly align them. Something like so:

```
dd, dt {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note: You probably also want to make the CSS selector a bit more specific than the example above.

Comment: Thanks ,  i tried your code, but as this is magento site, the values willl be saved in database & html structure  of inspect element is different than in real file, is there any way to fix the issue with only css ?

Comment: It will be hard, because somehow it has to know that it needs to break into a new row after two dropdowns. Alternatively, you can also add fixed widths to the dd and dt elements to force them to use a new row after 100% of the space being filled. But semantically, wrapping them around a div adds more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for support,  i found solution , i 'm sorry that as i am poor in coding , i failed to follow your solution properly .....